# Laravel 5 Delete more as one row from database with one command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What is the best way to delete more as one row from the database with one command?

Here I have coded it for example: Delete 1 Product in my DB but it must delete before also Orders with the same unique id

> ERROR: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a
>   parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Controller:

```
public function DeleteItem($uniqueid){
    $purchases = Purchase::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->delete();
    $product = Product::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->delete();
    return redirect()->back();;
}
```

I have an error in my code I know, anyone know how I can change it?

If the Product not sold its deleted without this line:

```
$purchases = Purchase::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->delete();
```

First 2 other things (Purchases and Feedback) must deleted, if not exist ignore the other lines and delete only the Product with:

```
public function DeleteItem($uniqueid){
    $product = Product::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->delete();
    return redirect()->back();;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `have an error in my Code i know`
What is that error?

Comment: you have 2 ';;' in your code

Comment: ERROR: Purchase must deleted first from same Product unique id

Comment: return redirect()->back();; with double semicolon

Comment: Error Updated in Question.

Comment: What is your table structure? Many to Many right? A purchase contains multiple products and a product can be in multiple purchases

Comment: Products can saved in 2 Tables. Products and Purchases. If someone buy it then goes to purchase and save it with same ID.

Comment: Check the `ON DELETE CASCADE` part: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

The error shown is coming from the database. It's related to foreign key. You're trying to delete an Element which has children referencing foreign keys to it.
If Purchase has One or Many Product, make sure that in your migration, where you define the foreign key you also instruct it to delete when the parent is deleted.

```
$table->foreign('purchase_id')->references('id')->on('purchases')->onDelete('cascade');
```

This way if you do `Purchase::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->delete();` it will also delete products attached to it.
[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)